# Disable menu item unless exactly one item is selected with PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyside

Working with a [`QMenu`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmenu.html) in PySide, I want to disable a menu item based on a [`QListWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html) selection count. If the selection count is exactly one then the 'Edit Item' action should be enabled, otherwise it should be disabled. How can I do this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Modules
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

# Variables
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
listItems = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]

# widget
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self,):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        # formatting
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Input List")

        # widgets
        self.itemList = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.itemList.addItems(listItems)
        self.itemList.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

        # context menu
        self.edit_menu = QtGui.QMenu()
        removeItem = self.edit_menu.addAction('Remove Item')
        removeItem.triggered.connect(self.RemoveItem)

        editItem = self.edit_menu.addAction('Edit Item')
        editItem.triggered.connect(self.EditItem)

        self.itemList.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.itemList.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_context_menu)
        self.itemList.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.EditItem)

        # layout
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.itemList, 0, 0)
        self.show()       

    def on_context_menu(self, pos):
        self.edit_menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(pos))

    def EditItem(self):
        print "Edit Item"

    def RemoveItem(self):
        print "Remove Item"

# Main
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few changes you need to make, but you can do this by disabling the [`QAction`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qaction.html#enabled-prop).

First change, make your `editItem` variable accessible throughout the class.

```
self.editItem = self.edit_menu.addAction('Edit Item')
self.editItem.triggered.connect(self.EditItem)
```

(You may want to do this to the `remoteItem` as well, for consistency)

Next, in `on_context_menu`, you need to check how many items you have selected. Then you enable/disable your menu option based on that logic:

```
def on_context_menu(self, pos):
    if len(self.itemList.selectedItems()) == 1:
        self.editItem.setEnabled(False)
    else:
        self.editItem.setEnabled(True)
    self.edit_menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(pos))
```

---

Examples:

With only one item selected:

[image: One item selected]

With more than one item selected:

[image: More than one item selected]